# Finding the minimal value a in list L given n and e, and (n/a) < e

Tags: python, min

This is what I've come up with so far. I've replaced user inputs with fixed numbers for now to make troubleshooting faster.

```
    n = 5
    e = 0.5
    L = range(1, 20+1)
    k = 0
    a = min(element for element in L if element > k)
    while (n/a) > e:
        k = k + 1
        a = min(element for element in L if element > k)
        if (n/a) < e:
            print(a)
    if (n/a) < e:
        print(a)
```

If I remove part of the code, so that I'm left with:

```
    n = 5
    e = 0.5
    L = range(1, 20+1)
    k = 0
    a = min(element for element in L if element > k)
    o = n/a
    if 0 < e:
        print(o)
```

Then everything works fine. The problem of course is that I have to manually add 1 to the value of k  in order to find the min a which meets the set conditions.

This is part of an assignment, the other part is to create a fibonacci sequence. I've managed to figure out that part. In the context of the assignment, n would still be a random integer user input, e would be a random float user input, a would be the min number in the fibonacci sequence where n/a < e.

Comment: So you need to find `a`, such that `a` is the minimum value of all the elements in the list, for which `n/a < e`? You're already almost there with your generator expression and `min` function...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to find `a`, such that `a` is the minimum value of all the elements in the list, for which `n/a < e`.

It's quite easy to encode the condition on your valid `a` values as a generator over L, and then take the minimum:

```
min(a for a in L if n/a < e)
```